# Why are the bitcoin I mined stuck in the approval stage?

Tags: fraud, withdrawal

I have mined my bitcoin. But after three months, it is still in the approval stage. Why doesn't it enter my new wallet? How can I withdraw them?

Answer (score 4):

> it is still in the approval stage

That's not how bitcoin mining works, there is no approval stage.

Normally when you mine bitcoin you set up the new block template to pay the mining reward directly into your wallet. If you mine as part of a mining pool, the pool pays directly into your wallet.

For me, words like "approval stage" strongly suggest some sort of scam to trick you out of money.